# Determining sample size when given Confidence Interval and margin of error in a finite population

Tags: sampling, sample-size, proportion, finite-population

I'm trying to determine n, the sample size.

We have $N=580$ and we want to estimate population proportion, $p$, at a 95%-CI and a margin of error of $0.10$, then I get

$$n=Npq / (N-1)D + pq$$

where $D= B^2 / 4$ to be about $n=86$.

But what if instead we keep that same margin of error at $0.10$ and now only want a 90%-CI, if we use the same formula don't we get the same $n$?

Am I using the formula wrong here?

Comment: Proportion of what? Is this binomial data? What's B? Why do you want a smaller N than 580? Are you sampling from the original 580 or is it a new random sample? What are you trying to find out from the sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formulas concerning the calculation of the sample size to estimate a proportion $p$ in for finite populations are provided on [this website](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/lesson/6/6.3). It also contains the derivations.

In short, the sample size necessary for estimating a population proportion $p$ of a finite population with $(1-\alpha)100\%$ confidence and a margin of error no larger than $\epsilon$ is:

$$
n = \frac{m}{1+\frac{m-1}{N}}
$$
where
$$
m=\frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^{2}\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{\epsilon^{2}}.
$$
$N$ denotes the population size, $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ the $(1-\alpha/2)$-quantile of the standard normal distribution and $\hat{p}$ the estimated proportion.

For $N=580, \alpha=0.05, \epsilon=0.1, \hat{p}=0.5$ (i.e. 95% confidence), we get $n\approx 83$. If we take $\alpha = 0.1$ which corresponds to 90% confidence, we get $n\approx 61$.

**The more precise we want our estimate of the popultion proportion to be, the higher our sample size needs to be.**

This means that the lower $\alpha$, the higher the necessary sample size will be. The following graph illustrates this (for $N=580, \epsilon=0.1, \hat{p}=0.5$):
[image: Sample size alpha]

The necessary sample size will also increase with *decreasing* margin of error $\epsilon$ (note the reversed $x$-axis; graph for $N=580, \alpha=0.05, \hat{p}=0.5$):

[image: Sample size margin of error]

Comment: Why, mathematically, do I need to know the estimated population proportion ex-ante to determine sample size? I have been looking for the reasoning, but also the site you linked does not explan that and just assumes a p-hat of 0.5. Do we always assume p-hat of 0.5 when we have not taken a pre-sample? Does our estimated required sample size change during the sampling process the closer we get to the population p? So if we have no clue about p-hat and after some sample n we have not yet found a success, we just stop and conclude p is between 0 and the error we initially set?

Comment: And, should I post the comment above in a separate question?

Comment: Also, is this true for small p? And what is a small p? 10%? 3%? 0.3%?

Comment: @iraserd $\hat{p}=0.5$ is usually taken because it's the worst-case scenario. The standard error is largest when $p=0.5$. So by taking $\hat{p}=0.5$ we're on the safe side. If you have an a-priori estimate of the population proportion, you could take that instead. You certainly could design a sequential approach, where you update your estimate on the fly. I assume that Bayesian methods would be suited for that. This approach is also valid for small $p$, as far as I'm aware. What a small $p$ is is subjective.